# How can I assign a View Page on a Domain?

Tags: views, 7, domain-access

On my Drupal 7, I assign Views Block by using **Domain Access** and **Domain Context** on a node(a node that already assigned to a domain). How can I assign a Views Page with Domain Access? The Views Page "**Path**" does not have the domain option, which I only can assign to the default domain. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

[Domain Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_views)

This module should provide that integration. It is supposed to link the domain access module and views together.

Comment: This allow me to add domain access into "filter". I don't see how to allow me to assign to a domain with path.